# when window resizing, transform.translate didn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, css, transform, translate

I want to make a page that automatically places boxes like Pinterest.

So, I made a code that grasps the size and position of the boxes to be placed with javascript and places them using transform.translate of css.

But, I have some problem.
When I refreshed the browser, it was arranged very well as I want,
but when I resize the browser, it seems to be arbitrarily arranged.
What's the problem Shall it?
Please, help me!!

[What I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUIjD.png)

[Real](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fsrq.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Transform.translate</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        div {
            width: 109px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        div:nth-child(2) {
            height: 200px;
        }

        div:nth-child(5) {
            height: 150px;
        }

        div:nth-child(11) {
            height: 180px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="allocate()" onresize="allocate()">
    <div class="box">0</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">11</div>
    <div class="box">12</div>
    <div class="box">13</div>
    <div class="box">14</div>
    <div class="box">15</div>
    <div class="box">16</div>
    <div class="box">17</div>
    <div class="box">18</div>
    <div class="box">19</div>

    <script>
        function allocate() {
            const obj = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
            const gap = 10;

            const parent = document.querySelector('.box').offsetParent;
            const parentT = parent.offsetTop;
            const parentL = parent.offsetLeft;
            const parentH = parent.offsetHeight;
            const parentW = parent.offsetWidth;
            const objW = 100;
            const cntV = Math.floor(parentW / (objW + gap));

            let calcX = parentL;
            let calcY = parentT;
            let elT = 0;
            let elW = 0;
            let elH = 0;
            let uElL = 0;
            let uElB = 0;
            let rect;
            let rectUpObj;

            for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                rect = obj[i].getBoundingClientRect();
                if (i < cntV) {
                    elW = rect['width'];
                    elH = rect['height'];

                    obj[i].style.transform = "translate(" + calcX + "px, " + calcY + "px)";
                    calcX += elW + gap;
                    calcY -= elH;
                } else {
                    rectUpObj = obj[(i - cntV)].getBoundingClientRect();
                    uElL = rectUpObj['left'];
                    uElB = rectUpObj['bottom'];
                    elT = rect['top'];

                    calcX = uElL;
                    calcY = -(elT - uElB - gap);

                    obj[i].style.transform = "translate(" + calcX + "px, " + calcY + "px)";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to act on a resize event on the window - I can't see anywhere in your code where you are listening for one. Resize is not the same as reload (though it may share a lot of the code of course).

Comment: I just used onresize in body tag.